# Storing a file in the blobstore from a URL in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, url, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I want to retrieve a file form a URL like http://www.abc.com/files/file.pdf and store in the blobstore... how do I do this?

Right now it only allows from form posts ...

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction.html and then POST it yourself?

Chances are Google won't allow you to just pass it arbitrary URLs anytime soon to avoid using it as a DDOS.